# Calculate sum of budget

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**I have a table budget like this:**

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╦═══════════╦══════╗
║ Id ║ Site ║ Rayon ║   Date    ║ Amt  ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╬═══════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║   20 ║    23 ║ 2015-11-3 ║  200 ║
║  2 ║   40 ║     2 ║ 2015-12-4 ║   20 ║
║  3 ║   20 ║     3 ║ 2015-11-4 ║  400 ║
║  4 ║   30 ║    13 ║ 2015-11-5 ║  500 ║
║  5 ║   20 ║    23 ║ 2015-08-3 ║  200 ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╩═══════════╩══════╝
```

How to calculate the sum of amt from today till the end of month and from today till the end of year ?

Comment: Did you try anything? Look at Group By and Datepart.

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: @rajeshmpanchal sql server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a problem such as this, the first thing you need to do is understand how to calculate "the end of this month" and "the end of this year". Using sql2008, you do not have access to a helpful function [`EOMONTH()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213020.aspx) so you must calculate this yourself.

There are [a few different ways of doing this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samlester/archive/2013/09/23/eomonth-equivalent-in-sql-server-2008-r2-and-below.aspx) but I've gone for one which will calculate a few millisonds before midnight on the last day of the current month, and the last day of the current year.

```
declare @date DATETIME = getdate()

select dateadd(millisecond,-3,DATEADD(MONTH,datediff(MONTH,0,@date)+1,0)) as EOMONTH
select dateadd(millisecond,-3,DATEADD(year,datediff(year,0,@date)+1,0)) as EOYEAR
```

<sub>(Note: the `-3` is due to sql server's `dattime` data type having a [minimum accuracy of 3ms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187819.aspx) so taking 3 ms from the beginning of next month/next year is as accurate as you're going to get. In any case it matters very little all we're trying to do is get a date boundary as close to the end of the month/end of the year as possible)</sub>

---

Given this bit is worked out, you could use them individually in 2 different queries

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @eomonth DATETIME = dateadd(millisecond,-3,DATEADD(MONTH,datediff(MONTH,0,@date)+1,0))
DECLARE @eoyear DATETIME = dateadd(millisecond,-3,DATEADD(year,datediff(year,0,@date)+1,0)) 

SELECT SUM(amt) FROM Budget
WHERE date >= @now AND date <=@eomonth

SELECT SUM(amt) FROM Budget
WHERE date >= @now AND date <= @eoyear
```

Or, you could combine them

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATE<@eomonth THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) AS summonth,
      SUM(CASE WHEN DATE<@eoyear THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) AS sumyear
FROM Budget 
WHERE Date>=@date
```

Comment: I don't like all those manipulations with milliseconds. It is getting not straightforward what you are doing.

Comment: What's not straightforward? Take [the minimum accuracy - 3ms] from the beginning of next month/next year. It's about as straightforward as you can get in SQL2008

Comment: For novice it is hard to understand why 3 millisecond? Why not 5 or 47 milliseconds?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri that's a valid point, i'll add some explanation

Comment: All that shamanism is just redundant as you can change inclusive cheking to exclusive. That is what I am saying. `date < @eoyear`

Comment: Yes, if you remove of the `-3ms` part you can, it's half a dozen of one and six of the other.

Answer (score 1):

For end of current month:

```
SELECT SUM(Amt) AS Amt 
FROM TableName
WHERE Date >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND 
      Date < DATEADD(m, 1, DATEADD(dd, -DAY(GETDATE()) + 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
```

For end of current year:

```
SELECT SUM(Amt) AS Amt 
FROM TableName
WHERE Date >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND 
      Date < CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1 AS char(4)) + '0101'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your sql version is older to support system function called [EOMONTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213020.aspx)

> This simple function will be equivalent for **EOMONTH.** This function will be very useful in complex date calculation by reducing query length.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.endofmonth(@date DATETIME= NULL)
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
RETURN DATEADD(DD, -1, DATEADD(MM, +1, DATEADD(DD, 1 - DATEPART(DD, ISNULL(@date,GETDATE())), ISNULL(@date,GETDATE()))))
END
```

**Query to perform:**

```
SELECT dbo.endofmonth(DEFAULT)  --Current month-end date
SELECT dbo.endofmonth('02/25/2012') --User-defined month-end date
```

**Your situation**

```
/**** To get end of current month ****/

SELECT SUM([amt]) FROM budget WHERE [date] >= getdate() AND [date] <= CONVERT(DATE,dbo.endofmonth(DEFAULT))

/**** To get end of current year  ****/
SELECT SUM([amt]) FROM budget WHERE [date] >= getdate() AND [date] <= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, -1))
```